# Change column type in SQL Server Database project

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I've got SQL Server Database Project in Visual Studio. In my Tables folder, I have an Employee.sql file that looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee] (
    [Id]                                    INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyId]                             VARCHAR (9)   NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeId]                            VARCHAR (10)  NOT NULL,
    [HireDate]                              VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
);
GO
```

I want to change that `HireDate` column to be a `DATE` property. I don't care about losing its existing data. So, I just want to drop that column and replace it with `DATE`. This is what I want to change it to:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee] (
    [Id]                                    INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyId]                             VARCHAR (9)   NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeId]                            VARCHAR (10)  NOT NULL,
    [HireDate]                              DATE          NULL,
);
GO
```

The problem is, when I run the publish.xml file, I get an error. I think I need to drop the existing column first (again, I don't care about data loss for it). How can I drop that column before the Employee.sql file is published?

This is the error I get when running publish.xml:

```
(144,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
(144,0): SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] ALTER COLUMN [HireDate] DATE NULL;

The statement has been terminated.
An error occurred while the batch was being executed.
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @DanGuzman I added it to the question just now.

Comment: Update the bad dates (or all dates) to NULL in a pre-deployment script.

Comment: I suspect you have some bogus data in [HireDate].   To identify the problem records try Select * from Employee Where try_convert(date,HireDate) is null and HireDate is not null

Answer (score 0):

Use a couple of `ALTER` statements:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee DROP COLUMN HireDate;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee ADD HireDate date NULL;
GO
```

Comment: Where? If I try adding that to my Employeel.sql file, VS gives me this error: `SQL70001: This statement is not recognized in this context.`